# How to customize an entity property in Sylius?

Tags: symfony, model, doctrine, entity, sylius

I'm working on a Sylius application and want to modify a property of an entity.

To be more concrete: What I want to achieve, is to make the `ProductVariant.onHand` (or actually the corresponding column in the database) `nullable`.

The documentation of Sylius provides an auspicious article "[Customizing Models](https://docs.sylius.com/en/latest/customization/model.html)". But it doesn't describe, how to change the definition of an existing property.

**How to modify a property of a Sylius (Core) entity like `ProductVariant.onHand`?**

---

What I tried so far: I extended the `Sylius\Component\Core\Model\ProductVariant` and added a Doctrine annotation to the `onHand` property:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="sylius_product_variant")
 */
class ProductVariant extends BaseProductVariant
{
    ...
    /**
     * ...
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $onHand = 0;
    ...
}
```

Well, `extend`ing the class was definitely a correct step. And it also worked correctly:

```sh
$ bin/console debug:container --parameter=sylius.model.product_variant.class
 ------------------------------------ ----------------------------------- 
  Parameter                            Value                              
 ------------------------------------ ----------------------------------- 
  sylius.model.product_variant.class   App\Entity\Product\ProductVariant  
 ------------------------------------ -----------------------------------
```

But the naïve adding of the property definition led to an error:

```sh
$ ./bin/console doctrine:schema:validate
  Property "onHand" in "App\Entity\Product\ProductVariant" was already declared, but it must be declared only once
```

Comment: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/tutorials/override-field-association-mappings-in-subclasses.html

Edit: I don't recommend making it nullable, it will probably break the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity configs can be overridden by adding the `AttributeOverrides` annotation:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="sylius_product_variant")
 * @ORM\AttributeOverrides({
 *     @ORM\AttributeOverride(
 *         name="onHand",
 *         column=@ORM\Column(
 *             name="on_hand",
 *             type="integer",
 *             nullable=true
 *         )
 *     )
 * })
 */
class ProductVariant extends BaseProductVariant
{
    ...
    /**
     * ...
     * no changes
     */
    protected $onHand;
    ...
}
```

Relevant Doctrine docu articles:

- [Override Field Association Mappings In Subclasses](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/current/tutorials/override-field-association-mappings-in-subclasses.html#override-field-association-mappings-in-subclasses)
- [Inheritance Mapping -> Overrides](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/current/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#overrides)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like ProductVariant has it's mapping in config files.

If a bundle defines its entity mapping in configuration files instead of annotations, you can override them as any other regular bundle configuration file. The only caveat is that you must override all those mapping configuration files and not just the ones you actually want to override.

https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/bundles/override.html#entities-entity-mapping

You could also try to create a new entity with the desired mapping (you will need to add all of the columns yourself) and point sylius.model.product_variant.class to this new class.

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow! ) Thank you for your answer. I got the entity configs overridden by adding [Attribute Override](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/current/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#attribute-override) annotations. It works, but it would be nice to get it overridden in the configs. How to do that?

Comment: Attribute override could be ugly but it works :) You can create a new entity and set `sylius.model.product_variant.class: App\Entity\MyClass`